How to implement MongoDB change stream in NestJS application using Mongoose driver?
I have two applications, one built with NestJS and the other with Express. Both are connected to MongoDB Atlas, and I have a user table with only one column: name. I'm trying to implement real-time updates on this table using MongoDB change streams.
Express Application

main()
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB'));
async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect(mongoDB);
}

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  await userMOdel.SomeModel.create({ name: 'Mohmad' });
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

Express User Schema

// Require Mongoose
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Define a schema
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
});

const SomeModel = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);

const changeStream = SomeModel.watch();

changeStream.on('change', (change) => {
  console.log('Mongodb Change===============');
});

module.exports = {
  SomeModel,
};

Nestjs Application

@Schema()
export class User {
    @Prop({
        type: String,
    })
    name: string;
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);

@Injectable()
export class ChangeStreamService implements OnModuleInit {
    constructor(
        @InjectModel(User.name)
        private readonly userModel: Model<typeof User & Document>,
        @InjectConnection() private connection: Connection,
    ) {}

    // onModuleInit() {
    //     const changeStream = this.userModel.watch();
    //     changeStream.on('change', (change) => {
    //         console.log('Change:', change);
    //     });

    //     changeStream.on('error', (change) => {
    //         console.log('Error:', change);
    //     });
    // }

    onModuleInit() {
        this.connection.db
            .collection('users')
            .watch()
            .on('change', (change) => {
                console.log('Change:', change);
            });
    }
}

Inside Module I have imported like this
 MongooseModule.forFeature([ {
                name: User.name,
                schema: UserSchema,
            }]

provider of same module 
 providers: [
       
        ChangeStreamService,
    ],

Now, In the Express application, I've successfully implemented change stream functionality and can listen to changes made on the database. However, in the NestJS application, I'm encountering difficulties. Despite using the Mongoose driver, I'm not receiving any updates.
Could someone guide how to correctly implement MongoDB change streams in a NestJS application using the Mongoose driver? Any code examples or explanations would be greatly appreciated.

my case like this and it's worked
 const changeStream = this.actuatorDeviceModel.watch();
    changeStream.on('change', (cb) => console.log('data', cb.fullDocument)); //return newest data
    

